# How can I modify the power button behaviour?

Tags: shutdown

I want the PC to shut down without any dialogue, but let time for the applications to close properly.

One solution is, to change `powerbtn.sh` to: `shutdown -h now` but that does not wait for all applications to close.

Answer (score 11):

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power shutdown`

will change your the behaviour of the power button of your system from interactive (default) to immediate normal shutdown.

The command is `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power <option>`

Available options are:

- Blank: does nothing
- Suspend: makes your system suspend
- Shutdown: starts a normal issued shutdown procedure
- Hibernate: hibernates your system
- Nothing: does nothing
- Log out: log your user out

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  Where is this documented?

Comment: I don't know where this is documented. Possibly it is not. You can see the set of valid values with the `gsettings range` command. In this case, `gsettings range org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power`. Right now, in Fedora 22, the valid values are 'blank', 'suspend', 'shutdown', 'hibernate', 'interactive', 'nothing', and 'logout'. This list includes "interactive" which isn't in Bruno's list, and they are all lower case, with no spaces in "logout". I'm confident this list is syntactically correct, and Bruno's is not. No offense to Bruno.

Comment: I just add the point that you should not run this command as a root.

Comment: This key was renamed from `button-power` to `power-button-action` at some point.

Answer (score 11):

**To do it GUI:**

Install dconf-tools:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

open dconf-editor from dash or just run `dconf-editor &` in terminal

Navigate to `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power` and set your default button-power action there:

[image]

replace suspend by shutdown.

Comment: Confirmed that this worked for a fully updated Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.