# Power button closes apps?

Tags: suspend, vlc, qbittorrent

When I press the power button to suspend, vlc and qbittorrent exit. It's really annoying cause some times I accidentally hit it and everything closes. Anyone know why or how to fix it?

Comment: you want to dumb your power button(I mean not doing any action)

Comment: refer here [http://askubuntu.com/modify-the-power-button-behaviour](http://askubuntu.com/questions/430776/how-can-i-modify-the-power-button-behaviour)